# conda hangs indefinitely when installing/activating R

Tags: r, bash, conda

Some time yesterday I started having issues with (mini)conda and environments containing R. Basically installing R into an environment, or activating an environment containing `r-base` (or some dependency thereof) reproducibly causes the conda process to completely freeze the terminal. Ctrl+c does nothing, hitting enter doesn't even create newlines. It's completely frozen.

The following reproduces the error for me:

```
conda create -n r-env r-base
conda activate r-env
```

This just hangs indefinitely (or at least it lasted overnight with no change).

[image: conda hanging in my console after trying to run "conda activate r-env"]

I've already tried removing conda and reinstalling it, and removing most of my environments.

...any ideas?

edit: Somehow it's conda-forge's version of r-base that does this... Removing it from the list of channels in my `condarc` means this no longer hangs. Strange thing is that conda-forge's r-base was last updated 7 days ago and I've not had issues until yesterday.

Comment: Is the "edit" an answer to this question, maybe post as answer below? Or close as not reproducible?

Comment: No it's not really an "answer" unless you think "just don't use conda-forge" is a decent solution to this problem..

Comment: Probably has to do with what gets done in the `envs/r-env/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-r-base.sh` script, which is run during activation. The only heavy lifting there is `R CMD javareconf`. Maybe you can try running that on its own in a shell to see how it behaves. Possibly want to use `envs/r-env/bin/R CMD javareconf`, to test specifically with the Conda env's `R`.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/conda-forge/r-base-feedstock/issues/67. However, also worth noting that there aren't substantial differences between [Conda Forge's `activate-r-base.sh`](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-base-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/activate-r-base.sh) and [Anaconda's `activate-r-base.sh`](https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/r-base-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/activate-r-base.sh), aside from some `export` statements, plus the `R CMD javareconf` hasn't changed in years.

Comment: R CMD javareconf fails if I call that with `r-env/bin/R` because it can't find the gcc in the conda env (`/bin/sh: 1: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: not found`). Not sure how to step through the activation process to figure out where it's hanging

Comment: You can manually retrieve the string of steps of activation with `~/miniconda3/condabin/conda shell.posix activate r-env`. At its core, Conda activation is an `eval` of that string.

Comment: That's a huge tip, thank you. Seems that adding `alias R="radian"` was the culprit.

Comment: merv, if you want to add an answer I'm happy to accept it as I wouldn't have found the cause without your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Debugging Conda Activation

Conda activation is primarily about managing environment variables in shell session. For POSIX shells, the core of what gets run can be viewed using

```bash
# need to use the actual binary `conda` 
~/miniconda3/condabin/conda shell.posix activate r-env
```

For me, this shows several Conda-specific environment variables being set, plus four activation scripts associated with the packages:

- gfortran_osx-64
- r-base
- clang_osx-64
- clangxx_osx-64

I would try running each of these in sequence to find where things are getting stuck.

It may also be useful to point out the `set -x` command for BASH, to trace all the commands getting run. E.g., one might try something like:

```bash
set -x && . ~/miniconda3/envs/r-env/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-r-base.sh && set +x
```

to trace through that particular activation script.

### Other Conda Activation Notes

One can view the BASH source for `conda activate` with:

```bash
type conda
type __conda_activate
```

But this is unlikely where the issue is happening, since this appears particular to the environment with `conda-forge::r-base` installed.